# Eclipse css content-assist (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, eclipse, twitter-bootstrap, content-assist

I cannot seem to figure out why content assist is not working for HTML classes in Eclipse. I have the Eclipse PDT and Web Developer Tools installed. Content assist works fine with PHP files, and standard HTML tags, but I'm sorely missing the ability to scroll a list of CSS boostrap classes (e.g., Twitter bootstrap).

I just switched from Netbeans to Eclipse, and this worked great in Netbeans.

Now I only get proposals for `div` and `class`, but that's where proposals end.

`<div class="no more proposals">`

I've already looked at file associations, editor->content assist settings, include paths, etc. Any other suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's it. I've had it with Eclipse and Netbeans. Eclipse is awesome, until I worked on trying to get content assist working for html classes for hours with no success. Netbeans had it all, including content assist even for html class elements, but the IDE continued to freeze time after time - cursor spins and spins and spins...

I just installed **PHPStorm** from Jetbrains, and this IDE needed absolutely no help from me to get setup and running. I had my project open, tested code assist on everything successfully, navigated around and found all the views I needed.

I have no problem paying for a product if it works as designed, especially if I don't have to spend hours trying to figure out how to get some feature to work. Time is money, and dropping a few dollars to get back hours of my life is **well worth it**.

Incidentally, I am running **Ubuntu Raring** desktop, and the versions of **Eclipse and Netbeans** I was struggling with were **Kepler and 7.3.1**, respectively. Version of **PHPStorm** that works like a dream is **6.0.3**.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of [Eclipse WTP Web Resources](https://github.com/angelozerr/eclipse-wtp-webresources).

It's because WTP doesn't provide this feature. If you need completion, validation, hyperlink, hover for CSS#ID, CSS#class, imgage, scripts and css files, I suggest you that you install [Eclipse WTP WebResources](https://github.com/angelozerr/eclipse-wtp-webresources/wiki/Installation-Update-Site).

Answer (score 0):

I know, that you asked this a year ago, but Eclipse is now providing autocomplete and suggestions. Simply with CTRL+Space, after you write at least one letter. It work quiet well.

I boosted it by installing Aptana (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/aptana-3).

Nowadays you can find plugins even for Less and SCSS. Just go to marketplace.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much an answer as a contribution.

My IDE of choice has been NetBeans 8.2 - it's intuitive and sets itself up without too much configuration (unlike Eclipse), but it seems that now even NB is being left behind and isn't supported as thoroughly as it once was.  One of the real frustrations is to run PHPUnit tests in NB interactively, because it inserts all kinds of legacy (unsupported) directives into the NB CLI phpunit command, which makes it virtually unusable for any meaningful development.  I know there's Apache NB 11.something, but it stalls during download, and even when I did get it to download and install it still contains the legacy phpunit directives, and none of the list of available frameworks for code-completion has been updated.  I didn't want to have to pay for an IDE.  :-(